# MulterError: Unexpected field getting error while uploading audio file to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer, cloudinary

Actually I am working on a podcast website and for that I am trying to upload audio file to API through **cloudinary** using multer. The audio is storing in cloudinary and I am also getting the file url properly I guess the error is occurring while storing the audio file url to database.

Following is the code for creating the API

```js
const Create = async(req,res)=>{
    const {CategoryName , Episodes} = req.body

    try{

        if(req.file){

            const audioresult = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
                req.file.path,
                {
                    resource_type: "video", 
                    public_id: "myfolder/mysubfolder/dog_closeup",
                    chunk_size: 6000000,
                    eager: [
                    { width: 300, height: 300, crop: "pad", audio_codec: "none" }, 
                    { width: 160, height: 100, crop: "crop", gravity: "south", audio_codec: "none" } ],
                    eager_async: true
                }
            )
            const audiourl = audioresult.url
            const file = dataUri(req).content;
            const result = await uploader.upload(file)
            const image = result.url;
            const Podcast = new Podcasts({
                CategoryName:CategoryName,
                Episodes:[{
                    EpisodeNo:req.body.EpisodeNo,
                    EpisodeName:req.body.EpisodeName,
                    EpisodeDescription:req.body.EpisodeDescription,
                    imageurl:image,
                    audio:audiourl
                }]
            })
            // console.log(imageurl)
            const Podcastresult = await Podcast.save()
            // console.log(Podcast)
            res.send(Podcastresult)
        }
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err)
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Following is the code of `multer.js`

```js
const multer = require('multer')
const Datauri = require('datauri/parser.js')
const path = require('path')

const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const Singleupload  = multer({storage}).single('file')

const audiostorage = multer.diskStorage({
    limits: { fileSize: 500000 }
})
const audioupload  =  multer({storage:audiostorage}).single("audio")
const middleware = {
    Singleupload , audioupload
}

const dUri = new Datauri()

const dataUri = req => dUri.format(path.extname(req.file.originalname).toString(), req.file.buffer);

module.exports = {dataUri , Singleupload,audioupload}
```

Following is the code of `router.post`

```js
router.post('/',[Singleupload,audioupload] ,Create)
```

Following is the image of the error that I am encountering

[image]

Following is the image of POSTMAN request

[image]